# How to solve 4 equation 4 unknown when some there are some product of unknowns

Tags: linear-algebra

recently I want to solve these four equations

$a(b+c) = 1$

$c^2+cd = 0$

$a^2+bc = 1$

$c(a+d) = 0$

Right now, I can get

$a = \frac{1}{b+c} $

$c = -d$

$a = -d$

However, I cannot actually solve one equation. How can I solve it? Thanks a lot

Comment: Are there any restriction on the unknowns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{cases}
a (b+c)=1\\
c^2+c d=0\\
a^2+b c=1\\
c (a+d)=0\\
\end{cases}
$$
if $c=0$ then $ab=1,a^2=1$ give infinite solutions $(1,1,c,d);\;(-1,-1,c,d)$.

Suppose $c\ne 0$. The system becomes
$$
\begin{cases}
a (b+c)=1\\
c+ d=0\\
a^2+b c=1\\
a+d=0\\
\end{cases}
$$
that is
$$
\begin{cases}
a b+ac=1\\
d=-c\\
a^2+b c=1\\
d=-a\\
\end{cases}\to a=c
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
a b+a^2=1\\
a^2+ab=1\\
c=a\\
d=-a\\
\end{cases}
$$
The system is indeterminate

solving $a^2+ab-1=0$ we get
$$a=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2+4}}{2}$$
So we have two sets of solutions, with $b$ as parameter
$$a=\frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{b^2+4}-b\right),c=\frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{b^2+4}-b\right),d=\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{b^2+4}+b\right)$$
$$a=\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{b^2+4}-b\right),c=\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{b^2+4}-b\right),d=\frac{1}{2} \left(b-\sqrt{b^2+4}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

Your conclusions are only true if $c\ne 0$. In that case, we have $a = c = -d$, and hence $a^2 + ab - 1=0$, which is a quadratic in $a$.

By the quadratic formula, we have $a = \dfrac {-b\pm \sqrt {b^2 + 4}}2 = c = -d$ as the solutions. Every value of $b$ will give a different solution.

For the case $c = 0$, the second and fourth equations are satisfied; we now have $a^2 = ab = 1$, which gives $a =b = \pm1$ and no restriction on the value of $d$.